# Using keyring Library With ConfigParser

Tags: python-2.7, python-keyring

I have a config file like this:

```
user=cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
password=somepassword
```

I want to save password to keyring. I can use keyrin password in python files with [keyring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring/0.9.2) library :

```
pass = keyring.get_password("system","administrator")
```

Is there any way to using keyring in config file? I'm using python 2.7 in my projects.

Comment: What do you mean under 'using keyring in config file'?

Comment: I don't want to write password as text but reading from keyring

Comment: @zwer I think it isn't safe way to get password as text in sourcecode

Comment: Well, it seems you already know how to retrieve a password from a keyring, so what exactly is a problem here?

Comment: @zwer I don't know how to use it in a file for example app.config

Comment: Don't use it in a config file, use it when you need the `password` value in the application that parses the config file - config files are not executable, they just provide data/instructions for the application that uses them.